# Allow only specific countries to connect to VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can i make Google Cloud VM only accessible only from certain countries ?

Like i need port 80 to be only access from INDIA then how can i do it ?

I have already tried using country ip block lists, but when I enter all IP's in source IP'S i get the error of character limit.

[image]

I've also tried creating multiple rules for same port by dividing IP list into parts but that also don't work.

Comment: Did you try creating the firewall rule from the command line? Example: gcloud compute firewall-rules create tcp-country-allow --network example-network --source-ranges 10.0.0.0/8 --allow tcp:80

Comment: @George Yes i tried using command line but got following error: "Must be a CIDR address range."

I specified IP address in following format : 
--source-ranges 1.6.0.0/15,1.22.0.0/15,1.38.0.0/15,1.186.0.0/15,14.0.60.0/24, . . . and so on...

after testing with 2 IPs i found out that the CMD only accept 1 IP in command line.

Comment: ok after check documentation i tried by replacing ,(comma) in source list to space but then got same error:
'ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Value for field 'resource.sourceRanges' is too large'

Comment: I tried it on my side and it's working like a charm with spaces. Maybe you are adding an address with an additional 0. for example: 1.186.0.0.0/15 which I tried and I received the same error message that you are receiving.

Comment: I tried again still same error, can you try with the following IP list: [link](http://pastebin.com/KUGF6pEx).  I am using it and getting  `too large`  error

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, this requires the use of too many rules; one workaround would be to use logic in your VM, such as the operating system firewall (`ufw`, `iptables`, etc).

However, configuring your web server to perform geolocalisation on requests by the client IP, return different content (a prohibitory page, etc) when desired, is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) now supports location-based traffic filtering through its Web Application Firewall. You can [set up geo-based access control](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/understanding-google-cloud-armors-new-waf-capabilities) by filtering on `request.origin`.